# std::find on a vector of object pointers

Tags: c++, class, vector, member

I have a class `A` with a member which is a vector of object pointers of another class `B`

```
class A
{
    std::vector<B*> m_member_A
```

Now I want to perform a `std::find` on `m_member_A`. 
E.g. 
`if(std::find(m_member_A.begin(), m_member_A.end(), B_obj*) != m_member_A.end())`

std::find doesn't make sense on such a vector. How do I achieve such a functionality?

How would it change if it were a vector of objects of B (not pointer)?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't make sense?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I guess he wants to compare by value and not the pointers

Comment: I meant what would it it mean to find a pointer.

Comment: @ontherocks It'd mean you found an object that is located at the same memory address as the value you passed in to `find`. I think you're looking for `find_if`, which accepts a predicate. Within the predicate you can dereference the pointer and call member functions etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find a value pointer at by the pointer, instead of a given pointer, you can use `std::find_if` with a suitable functor:

```
struct Foo
{
  int i;
};

bool operator==(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs) { return lhs.i == rhs.i; }

std::vector<Foo*> v = ....;

Foo f{42};

std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&f](const Foo* p) { return *p == f; });
```

Comment: @Jarod42 No I don't. Up to the user to pass a vector containing valid pointers.

Comment: So firstly I need to overload the comparison operator, since find uses comparison operator to compare. Am I right?

Comment: @ontherocks that is just an example. You can implement the all the comparison logic in the functor itself.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. On the other hand if I overload the comparison operator, std::find would work exactly like builtin data types....right?

Comment: @ontherocks Well, it would work if you had an `std::vector<Foo>`, but it won't work if your vector contains pointers. And you are not allowed to overload comparison operators for pointers.

Comment: Oh I see. So functor route would be the most generic solution then.

Answer (score 2):

Vector works perfectly fine with `std::find`

```
auto result = std::find(m_member_A.begin(), m_member_A.end(), itemToFind);
if (result != m_member_A.end()) {
  // found it!
}
```

Or if you need to dereference the pointer:

```
auto result = std::find_if(m_member_A.begin(), m_member_A.end(), 
  [] (B* item) { 
    if (item == nullptr) return false; // may want to do something else here
    return *item == someValue;
  });
if (result != m_member_A.end()) {
  // found it!
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/jKCrG5

Comment: If I deference the pointer I will be left with the object. What would "finding" an object mean? (since I haven't overloaded the comparison operator)

Comment: @ontherocks You would need to implement the criteria yourself in the lambda and return true when it is satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare values instead of comparing pointers, you might want to use std::find_if instead:

```
bool IsFoo (B* _item) {
    bool result = false;

    if ( _item != nullptr && _item->value == 1 ) //Whatever is your criteria
        result = true; 

    return result;
}

std::vector<B*> m_member_A;
B* instance = std::find_if (m_member_A.begin(), m_member_A.end(), IsFoo);
```

Comment: @Jarod42 True.. It was meant as quick example and not as a copy and paste kind of solution, I will update it anyway.